# Stateless session bean - time out error while waiting to get an instance from the free pool

Tags: ejb, jms, weblogic, pool, stateless

I am getting following exception. It is suspected that the problem occurs when lots of JMS messages are generated.

javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An invocation of EJB NeManagerAlarmProcessor(Application: onecontrol, EJBComponent: uigraphmanagement-emshealth-nemanageralarm.jar) timed out while waiting to get an instance from the free pool.; nested exception is: java.lang.RuntimeException: An invocation of EJB NeManagerAlarmProcessor(Application: onecontrol, EJBComponent: uigraphmanagement-emshealth-nemanageralarm.jar) timed out while waiting to get an instance from the free pool.
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:121)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy267.handleNotification(Unknown Source)
    at com.company.rm.uigraph.emshealth.nemanageralarm.messaging.UIAlarmMDB.onMessage(UIAlarmMDB.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor394.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Your ejb pool is empty and then, no instance is available to handle requests. What is the value of the max-beans-in-free-pool parameter in your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file ?

Comment: <wls:stateless-session-descriptor>
            <wls:pool>
                <wls:max-beans-in-free-pool>1</wls:max-beans-in-free-pool>
            </wls:pool>
        </wls:stateless-session-descriptor>

Comment: ok, in fact you have only 1 instance of this ejb in each server. That explains why you get this exception. You can remove the max-beans-in-free-pool parameter from the weblogic.xml file and redeploy your application. The ejb container will then create the necessary number of ejbs your application needs.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin are you sure, max-beans-in-free-pool parameter in weblogic.xml file? Because in my case I don't have such parameter in weblogic.xml

Comment: Yes it can be set in the weblogic -ejb-jar.xml  file.
If it is not present the default value is 1000.

Comment: In your earlier comment, you mentioned it as weblogic.xml instead of weblogic-ejb-jar.xml, that is why I was confused. Thankyou for the comment.